# SQL Script works in MySQL Workbench but when converted to PHP it does not

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, mysql-workbench

I have the following MySQL script that I can successfully run within the mySQL Workbench. I am trying to convert this to PHP. I have used the MySQL utility to generate the PHP code, but it is not updating the database table as it should. When I run the PHP code in my browser, I do not get any errors, just a blank white page. It appears that the PHP code executed without errors, but the database is not being updated with the file. I have left then user name and password data off of my post, but the code I am running has the correct info in the code. Any thoughts as to why it is not working?

SQL Script:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Test_Company.inventory data;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /Users/Test.User/Desktop/Data/Inventory Data.csv 
INSERT INTO TABLE Test_Company.inventory data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'

IGNORE 1 LINES
```

PHP Code:

```
$host="localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="/tmp/mysql.sock";
$user="";
$password="";
$dbname="Test_Company";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());


$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `Test_Company`.`inventory data`;  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Test.User/Desktop/Data/Inventory Data.csv'  INTO TABLE `Test_Company`.`inventory data`  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  IGNORE 1 LINES";

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //printf("%s, %s\n", $field1, $field2);
}
$stmt->close();
}

$con->close();

?>
```

Comment: MySQLi `prepare()/execute()` will not permit two SQL statements in one execution (delimited by `;`) Split the `TRUNCATE` action and the `LOAD DATA` action into two separate executions.

Comment: mysqli doesnt support executing multiple SQL statements with the function prepare.

Comment: Error messages?

Comment: As others have said, split your queries into multiple because mysqli doesn't allow more than one at once

Comment: I have split the statements into two separate executions. The TRUNCATE statement works and clears the database table, but the LOAD DATA is still not working. Also, no error messages...